# JQuery validation with default input

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using this technique to place default input in the text fields as a hint to users.

http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/default_text_fields_using_simple_jquery_trick.aspx

I would like to also validate the fields using jquery validate.

How can i get the validater to ignore the default input?

Comment: Don't do that, the semantics suck and the technique has accessibility issues. Use real labels. If you really want them under the input and to vanish when people try to use the control, then position them under the input, e.g. http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/label-work/example.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery.validation - how to ignore default values when validating mandatory fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733922/jquery-validation-how-to-ignore-default-values-when-validating-mandatory-field)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different method that does not actually add a value to the input fields for the hint. This might do the trick: http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/

Basically, your label field is positioned directly within the text box. Caveats are your form design needs to be able to accommodate such an approach.