# How to Show error on Validation in Jquery when Default values exist

Tags: jquery, validation, input

i'm new to Jquery tried searching google everywhere with no luck, i am looking for a validation rule/ or function to validate a form and to ask for required when the defautl value is in the form hence, not to count default value as valid. i tried couple of codes with no luck, my URL is http://jconstruction.us.cloudlogin.co/formtst.php

The Jquery Code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myform").validate({
        valid: function(input){
                    var value = $("input").val();
                    if(value == "test"){ return false;}
                       // check input value against your default values
                       // - If match, return false (is NOT valid)
                       // - If no match, return true (is valid)
                     },  

        debug: false,
        rules: {
          name: "required",
          email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          }
        },

        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('proc.php', $("#myform").serialize(), 
                            function(data) {
                $('#light').html(data);
                $('#light').show();
                $('#fade').show();
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Where the valid:function input is the one i tried that thought was the most functioanl however, i do not know what to put inside the function to validate. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2733922/344304

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element) {
    //check if its default value, if yes then invalidate  
    return !(element.value == element.defaultValue); 
});
```

Comment: i tried that with no luck, however , what is the code to check if value is yes? how is the if condtion stated in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(input)` needs to be either a class or an id, doesn't it? `.` or `#`?

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html)

This is the plugin that validates with default values

```
<form id="formID" class="formular" method="post">
     <input value="This is a placeholder" data-validation-placeholder="This is a placeholder" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="reqplaceholder" id="reqplaceholder" />
</form>



<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine

        jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, i have a question does the name of the input has to be reqplaceholder or it can be anything??